# setting up the babel plugin for spread operator correctly

Tags: javascript, babeljs, spread-syntax

Attempting to use babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread in my project. Installed the module.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread
```

.babelrc looks like.

```
{
    "presets": [
      ["env", {
        "include": ["babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread"]
      }]
    ]
  }
```

Registering babel in my main.js

```
// babel
require('babel-core/register')
require('babel-polyfill')
```

But the below code snippet still throws (Unexpected token) error

```
  return {
    ...state,
    hoverTrend: action.trend,
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The plugin [babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/) seemed to work fine for me. So basically first install it,

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread
```

And then add to .babelrc

```
{
    "plugins": ["transform-object-rest-spread"],
    "presets": [
        "env"
    ]
}
```