You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type when npm run build
I npm run build in my VueJS project and get this error. I don't know what it is, I did try some searchings and downgrading the Firebase version but not working I keep receiving this error message when building source.
My current Node version is 18.16.1 and npm version is 9.8.0
ERROR in ./node_modules/idb/build/index.js
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (90:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| }
| replaceTraps((oldTraps) => ({
|     ...oldTraps,
|     get: (target, prop, receiver) => getMethod(target, prop) || oldTraps.get(target, prop, receiver),
|     has: (target, prop) => !!getMethod(target, prop) || oldTraps.has(target, prop),
 @ ./node_modules/@firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js 5:0-29
 @ ./node_modules/firebase/app/dist/esm/index.esm.js
 @ ./src/main.js

This is my package.json file:
{
  "name": "my-vue-js-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "sieu.s",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "unit": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
    "test": "npm run unit",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "gcp-build": ""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "element-ui": "^2.13.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^10.13.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jszip": "^2.6.1",
    "jszip-utils": "^0.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-quill-editor": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^21.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jest": "^22.0.4",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^0.3.0",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-jest": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}


It's presumably this version, you can see that 90:4
refers to object spread syntax, https://www.npmjs.com/package/idb/v/7.1.1?activeTab=code . This is very specific to your webpack and babel configs which you didn't show. This possibly requires to upgrade both as they are really old

Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51229628/setting-up-the-babel-plugin-for-spread-operator-correctly

Hi Estus, I did put my webpack and babel config but it was too long because my post needed more detail not related to coding so I removed those files. I don't think upgrading webpack and babel is a good idea because my source is an old project. Last time I upgraded those packages, they broke my projects.

It's certainly expected that an upgrade will be a breaking change, depending on a case there could be just no other way. IIRC this is unnecessary in this case. Any way, these are things that are related, the question cannot be answered in its current state. I'd suggest to try what I said above and reask with new details if the problem persists. Make sure the package that causes the problem (idb) is transformed with babel (node_modules are supposed to be excluded by default)

Hi Estus, I downgraded my firebase version from 10.13.1 to 9.6.1 the error has disappeared. It seems like firebase with version >= 9.7.x is causing this error. Thanks for the great suggestion !
